# Is there a way to fix this "debconf-show" path issue?

Tags: ansible, passwords, mattermost, debconf

I am trying to set a root password for a MYSQL DB using ansible.  Iam using debconf however, it errors me out saying:

```
Failed to find required executable debconf-show in paths: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

My yaml file contains:

```
- name: set root password
  become: yes
  debconf:
    name: 'mysql-server'
    question: 'mysql-server/root_password'
    value: '{{mysql_password}}'
    vtype: 'password'
```

I am using centos7.  Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some host requirements that the `debconf` Ansible module [requires](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debconf_module.html#requirements).

Did you try adding them?

```
- name: Install debconf requirements
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - debconf
    - debconf-utils
```